# Google Analytics for Android not up-to-date with INSTALL_REFERRER intent deprecation?

Tags: android, google-analytics

Don't ask me why, but my customer uses Google Analytics (with a few more including Firebase Analytics) for its Android app. And obviously, removing Google Analytics is not an option ;)

Since `INSTALL_REFERRER` intent will be deprecated on March 1, 2020, I updated all analytics SDK which was using it but surprinsingly, Google Analytics implementation seems to not have been updated (see its guide: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-campaigns).

So my question, did someone found how to keep this feature with Google Analytics, knows if this feature will remain in Google Analytics or has a contact or a way to contact someone at Google to have this answer?

Note: I've filled an issue also on Google Analytics issue tracker (see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146163491)

Comment: Just an update: Google Analytics team is on it ;) (see the opened issue at Google)